# VB.NET Inheritance issue

Tags: vb.net, class, variables, inheritance, shadows

I've got A base class `Base` and `Sorter` and `Parser` classes derived from it .
The same thing with `BaseResult` with derived `SorterResult` and `ParserResult`.
`Base` has a `Result` field of `BaseResult` type, `BaseResult` has a `Log` field.
The reason why I've used a `Base` class, is because both of `Parser` and `Sorter` must write a Log.
Here's my code:

```
Public MustInherit Class Base
    Public Result As BaseResult
    Event LogChanged()
    Protected Sub AddLogLine(ByVal _logString As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_logString) Then Result.Log.Add(_logString)
        RaiseEvent LogChanged()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Sorter
    Inherits Base
    Public Shadows Result As SorterResult
    Sub New()
        Result = New SorterResult With {.Log = New List(Of String)}
    End Sub
    Sub Go()
        AddLogLine("Sorter started")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Parser
    Inherits Base
    Public Shadows Result As ParserResult

    Sub New()
        Result = New ParserResult With {.Log = New List(Of String)}
    End Sub
    Sub Go()
        AddLogLine("Sorter started")
    End Sub
End Class

Public MustInherit Class BaseResult
    Public Log As List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class SorterResult
    Inherits BaseResult
    '//SorterResult fields
End Class

Public Class ParserResult
    Inherits BaseResult
    '//ParsedResult fields
End Class
```

The issue here is that compiler sais(on pic below):[image]

***"variable 'Result' conflicts with variable 'Result' in the base class 'Base' and should be declared 'Shadows'."***  When I used Shadows keyword, warning disappeared, but I get a null reference exception on this line, because `Result` field is `Nothing`:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_logString) Then Result.Log.Add(_logString)
```

I can't assign a value to a `Result` variable in `Base` class constructor, because It must be of type `SorterResult` in `Sorter`, and `ParserResult` in `Parser`. What is the regular pattern here? Sorry my bad english.

[image]

Comment: you are not assigning `Result` in the `Class Base` when you are using [Shadows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3wytf6.aspx) You can use `MyBase` to assign. But I think your approach is worng. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4swkw24.aspx) will give more details on `Shadows`.

Comment: @bansi, can you suggest better approach? My whole pattern is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generics

```
Public MustInherit Class Base(Of TResult As BaseResult)
    Public Result As TResult

    Event LogChanged()

    Protected Sub AddLogLine(ByVal _logString As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_logString) Then Result.Log.Add(_logString)
        RaiseEvent LogChanged()
    End Sub

    Public MustOverride Sub Go()
End Class

Public Class Sorter
    Inherits Base(Of SorterResult)

    Sub New()
        Result = New SorterResult With {.Log = New List(Of String)}
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Go()
        AddLogLine("Sorter started")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Parser
    Inherits Base(Of ParserResult)

    Sub New()
        Result = New ParserResult With {.Log = New List(Of String)}
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Go()
        AddLogLine("Sorter started")
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, this is not a "beautiful" inheritance hierarchy. Inheritance should formulate relations like "a student is a person" where `student` derives from `person`. What do sorters and parsers have in common? Are they a `Base`? Are they loggers? Are they commands  (as suggests the `Go` method)? Is inheritance required here? Wouldn’t it be more appropriate to use aggregation?  I would  declare a completely independent logger class and inject it into classes. This allows you to be more flexible, as it enables you to inject different types of loggers.

```
Public MustInherit Class Logger
    Public Event LogChanged()

    Public MustOverride Sub AddLogLine(ByVal message As String)

    Protected Sub OnLogChanged()
        RaiseEvent LogChanged()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TextFileLogger
    Inherits Logger

    Public Overrides Sub AddLogLine(ByVal message As String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) Then
            'TODO: Write message to log file
            OnLogChanged()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can inject it like this:

```
Public Class SomeConsumerClass
    Private _logger As Logger

    Sub New(ByVal logger As Logger)
        _logger = logger
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        _logger.AddLogLine("Did something!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Use like this:

```
Dim obj As New SomeConsumerClass(New TextFileLogger())
obj.DoSomething()
```

If you have another kind of logger (XmlFileLogger, StringListLogger, DatabaseLogger...) it is now easy to use it without having to change all the classes using it.

Maybe you should even have only one global logger:

```
Dim globalLogger As New TextFileLogger()
Dim sorter As New Sorter(globalLogger)
Dim parser As New Parser(globalLogger)
```

Comment: Thanks, Oliver, I've learned something new today. Logging now works. The only problem here is that I still can't see another fields of `SorterResult` in `Sorter` methods(for example). Compiler still sees `Result` of type `BaseResult` there. The only way is to define variable of type `SorterResult`, work with it, and then assign it's value to `Result`? What do you think about whole pattern? Maybe I make things complicated? My idea is that `Result` holds all the information about derived classes work, including `Log`.

Comment: Have you declared `Public Result As TResult` in `Base` and `Inherits Base(Of SorterResult)` in `Sorter`?

Comment: I got more than I expected, now I have many things to think about. Thanks a lot again, Oliver! I fixed it, now all works. Wow!